# Setting become_user conditionally

Tags: ansible

I am trying to shutdown databases in a loop, the catch is some databases run as a different user and others just run as oracle. I login as oracle user and run the playbook and if the database is run as oracle user it goes through fine. If it is running as a different user I would like to become that user (oracle user has permissions to do that).

Here is my main playbook:

**[oracle@ansctrlsrv.localdomain epd3]$ cat test.yml**

```
---
- hosts: testdrive
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        db_list: "{{ lookup('file', 'vars/' ~ inventory_hostname ~ '.dblist')|from_yaml }}"
    - name: Shutdown running databases
      include_tasks: shutdowndb.yml
      loop: "{{ db_list }}"
```

DB list is as follows:

**[oracle@ansctrlsrv.localdomain epd3]$ cat vars/dbsrv.localdomain.dblist**

```
- ebs1
- ebs2
- ndb1
```

**[oracle@ansctrlsrv.localdomain epd3]$ cat shutdowndb.yml**

```
---
- debug: msg='Shutting down {{ item }}'
- name: Execute shutdown
  shell: id "{{ item }}"
  register: shutdown_output
  become: "{{ item is search('ebs') | ternary('yes','no') }}"
  become_user: "{{ item }}"
- debug: msg="{{ shutdown_output.stdout }}"
```

**[oracle@ansctrlsrv.localdomain epd3]$ cat inventory**

```
[testdrive]
dbsrv.localdomain
```

**[oracle@ansctrlsrv.localdomain epd3]$ ansible-playbook -i inventory test.yml**

> TASK [Execute shutdown] *** 
>   fatal: [dbsrv1.localdomain]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to dbsrv1.localdomain closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1} ...ignoring

I tried this question on another thread but got closed, so trying another hand after realizing a few issues myself such as being unable to run blocks of code with a loop, etc.
Appreciate any help.

[Set become user conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60009459/set-become-user-conditionally)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the line

```
shell: id "{{ item }}"
```

correct syntax (use `shell` only when necessary)

```
command: "id {{ item }}"
```

---

The playbook below

```
- hosts: testdrive
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        db_list: "{{ lookup('file', 'vars/' ~ inventory_hostname ~ '.dblist')|from_yaml }}"
    - name: Shutdown running databases
      include_tasks: shutdowndb.yml
      loop: "{{ db_list }}"
```

with the included tasks

```
$ cat shutdowndb.yml
  - debug:
      msg:
        - "shell: {{ 'shutdown.sh ' ~ item }}"
        - "become: {{ item is search('ebs')|ternary('yes', 'no') }}"
        - "become_user: {{ item }}"
```

give

```
    "msg": [
        "shell: shutdown.sh ebs1", 
        "become: yes", 
        "become_user: ebs1"
    ]

    "msg": [
        "shell: shutdown.sh ebs2", 
        "become: yes", 
        "become_user: ebs2"
    ]

    "msg": [
        "shell: shutdown.sh ndb1", 
        "become: no", 
        "become_user: ndb1"
    ]
```

---

> Q: "*Why the command whoami is still giving oracle rather than ebs1?"*

A: Short answer: Because `become` is not set to True.

**Debugging**

1) Is it possible to become all of the users in `db_list`? Yes.

```
- hosts: test_01
  become: no
  remote_user: admin

  vars:
    db_list: ['ebs1', 'ebs2', 'ndb1']

  tasks:

    - command: whoami
      become_user: "{{ item }}"
      become: true
      register: result
      loop: "{{ db_list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.results|json_query('[].stdout') }}"
```

give

```
    "msg": [
        "ebs1", 
        "ebs2", 
        "ndb1"
    ]
```

2) Does `search` and `ternary` work properly? Yes.

```
   - debug:
        msg: "{{ item is search('ebs')|ternary(true, false) }}"
      loop: "{{ db_list }}"
```

gives

```
    "msg": true
    "msg": true
    "msg": false
```

3) Does `become` and `become_user` work properly?. Yes.

```
    - command: whoami
      become_user: "{{ item }}"
      become: "{{ item is search('ebs')|ternary(true, false) }}"
      register: result
      loop: "{{ db_list }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ result.results|json_query('[].stdout') }}"
```

give

```
    "msg": [
        "ebs1", 
        "ebs2", 
        "admin"
    ]
```

Comment: I am at loss on getting the ternary operator to work, setting on this so getting no errors now:   `become: "{{ 'no' if item != 'ebs' else 'yes' }}" `. I put in     `command: "whoami"` to see if the become is working, it still prints `oracle` rather than `ebs1`.  Again appreciate your help.

Comment: The problem might be `become` expects Boolean not String. Try `...|ternary(True, False)`.

Comment: Looks like become can take both true/false or yes/no. Since this is not giving error, I will go with this for now:   `become: "{{ 'no' if item != 'ebs' else 'yes' }}"`   Could you help with why the command whoami is still giving `oracle` rather than `ebs1`.

Comment: I've added step-by-step debug. I can't do more for you. If you have any particular problem open a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think all you said is correct, its another error that I am ending up with. Posted another question. Working on that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062128/shared-connection-to-host-closed/

Comment: Just wanted to update it turns out that I am running into an issue with unprivileged user trying to become as another unprivileged user. You commented on that issue in your previous posts. I might have to abandon that use case for now. Again really appreciate your help.