# Shared connection to host closed

Tags: ansible

I am trying to change user for certain task unable to make it work. Getting the error `Shared connection to host closed`

Here is my playbook:

**cat test1.yml**

```
- hosts: hcmbox
  tasks:
    - name: Find out my identity Bourne
      command: "whoami"
      register: idoutput
      become: true
      become_user: ebs1

    - debug: msg="{{ idoutput.stdout }}"
```

I get this error:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory test1.yml                       

PLAY [hcmbox] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [srvdb1.localdomain]

TASK [Find out my identity Bourne] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [srvdb1.localdomain]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to srvdb1.localdomain closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
srvdb1.localdomain    : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Removed following two lines from playbook

```
      become: true
      become_user: ebs1
```

and executed again, here is the output:

```
PLAY [hcmbox] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [srvdb1.localdomain]

TASK [Find out my identity Bourne] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [srvdb1.localdomain]

TASK [debug] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [srvdb1.localdomain] => {
    "msg": "oracle"
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
srvdb1.localdomain    : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

The trust and everything looks ok to me:

```
[oracle@ansctrlsrv epd3]$ ansible all -i 'srvdb1,' -m command -a 'whoami' -u ebs1

srvdb1 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
ebs1
```

Even ssh works fine I checked it.

```
[oracle@ansctrlsrv epd3]$ ssh ebs1@srvdb1
Last login: Tue Feb  4 10:35:51 2020 from ansctrlsrv.localdomain
[ebs1@srvdb1 ~]$
```

I am at a loss why I am getting this error: `Shared connection to srvdb1.localdomain closed`

When I run with -vvv This is what I see:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory -vvv test3.yml 
ansible-playbook 2.8.4
  config file = /stage/ap/ansible/epd3/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/oracle/app/oracle/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 08:19:52) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39.0.1)]
Using /stage/ap/ansible/epd3/ansible.cfg as config file
host_list declined parsing /stage/ap/ansible/epd3/inventory as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
script declined parsing /stage/ap/ansible/epd3/inventory as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /stage/ap/ansible/epd3/inventory as it did not pass it's verify_file() method
Parsed /stage/ap/ansible/epd3/inventory inventory source with ini plugin

PLAYBOOK: test3.yml *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in test3.yml

PLAY [hcmbox] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [command] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /stage/ap/ansible/epd3/test3.yml:10
<dbsrv1.localdomain> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<dbsrv1.localdomain> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/oracle/app/oracle/.ansible/cp/9c1b54644d dbsrv1.localdomain '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~ && sleep 0'"'"''
<dbsrv1.localdomain> (0, '/oracle/app/oracle\n', '')
<dbsrv1.localdomain> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<dbsrv1.localdomain> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/oracle/app/oracle/.ansible/cp/9c1b54644d dbsrv1.localdomain '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1580841289.87-193361522034615 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1580841289.87-193361522034615="` echo /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1580841289.87-193361522034615 `" ) && sleep 0'"'"''
<dbsrv1.localdomain> (0, 'ansible-tmp-1580841289.87-193361522034615=/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1580841289.87-193361522034615\n', '')
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/commands/command.py
<dbsrv1.localdomain> PUT /oracle/app/oracle/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-23567JjjVQn/tmpwYZDSF TO /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1580841289.87-193361522034615/AnsiballZ_command.py
<dbsrv1.localdomain> SSH: EXEC sftp -b - -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/oracle/app/oracle/.ansible/cp/9c1b54644d '[dbsrv1.localdomain]'
<dbsrv1.localdomain> (0, 'sftp> put /oracle/app/oracle/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-23567JjjVQn/tmpwYZDSF /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1580841289.87-193361522034615/AnsiballZ_command.py\n', '')
<dbsrv1.localdomain> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<dbsrv1.localdomain> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/oracle/app/oracle/.ansible/cp/9c1b54644d dbsrv1.localdomain '/bin/sh -c '"'"'setfacl -m u:ebs1:r-x /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1580841289.87-193361522034615/ /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1580841289.87-193361522034615/AnsiballZ_command.py && sleep 0'"'"''
<dbsrv1.localdomain> (0, '', '')
<dbsrv1.localdomain> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<dbsrv1.localdomain> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/oracle/app/oracle/.ansible/cp/9c1b54644d -tt dbsrv1.localdomain '/bin/sh -c '"'"'sudo -H -S -n  -u ebs1 /bin/sh -c '"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-qtuzljmaohdcqewvlstmcepjcdwdxsiy ; /usr/bin/python /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1580841289.87-193361522034615/AnsiballZ_command.py'"'"'"'"'"'"'"'"' && sleep 0'"'"''
Escalation succeeded
<dbsrv1.localdomain> (1, '', 'Shared connection to dbsrv1.localdomain closed.\r\n')
<dbsrv1.localdomain> Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Shared connection to dbsrv1.localdomain closed.
<dbsrv1.localdomain> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: None
<dbsrv1.localdomain> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/oracle/app/oracle/.ansible/cp/9c1b54644d dbsrv1.localdomain '/bin/sh -c '"'"'rm -f -r /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1580841289.87-193361522034615/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'"'"''
<dbsrv1.localdomain> (0, '', '')
failed: [dbsrv1.localdomain] (item=ebs1) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
    "changed": false, 
    "item": "ebs1", 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to dbsrv1.localdomain closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", 
    "rc": 1
}

PLAY RECAP ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
dbsrv1.localdomain    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: You should run the playbook with `-vvv` to see if you get more information about how and why the connection is being closed.

Comment: I have posted the -vvv output in the original question. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

Which Python version is installed on your server?
Can you try to install python3 and add the path to python 3 in your inventory file.

It would look something like this:

`srvdb1.localdomain ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3`

Comment: Using this: Python version is `2.7.5` Here is the ansible.cfg [defaults] interpreter_python=/usr/bin/python stdout_callback = skippy Getting Python3 is going to be an uphill tasks for now, let me see if I can do that.

Comment: It looks like the issue seems to be related with unprevileged user trying to become as another user as described in: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#risks-of-becoming-an-unprivileged-user.  pipelining and setting allow_world_readable_tmpfiles to true did not work so far.

Comment: @calsaint I know this is 2 years later but did you manage to ever fix this? I'm having the exact same problem right now:)

Comment: Sorry @Stef, just logged in after a long time. I have given-up on that.